# C# deserialize with special characters like $

Tags: c#

Hello I have one json text inside this text there is one key which starts with $

```
string jsonText="{\"Version\":\"1.1\",\"Documents\":[{\"DocumentState\":\"Correct\",\"DocumentData\":{\"Name\":\"test\",\"$type\":\"Document\",\"Fields\":[{\"Name\":\"CustomerFullName\",\"$type\":\"Text\",\"SuspiciousSymbols\":\"0\",\"RecognizedValue\":\"\",\"Value\":\"\"},{\"Name\":\"CustomerBirthDate\",\"$type\":\"Text\",\"Value\":\"\"},{\"Name\":\"DocumentNumber\",\"$type\":\"Text\",\"SuspiciousSymbols\":\"0000000000\",\"RecognizedValue\":\"\",\"Value\":\"\"},{\"Name\":\"CustomerIsMarried\",\"$type\":\"Checkmark\",\"IsSuspicious\":false,\"Value\":true},{\"Name\":\"CustomerCounty\",\"$type\":\"Text\",\"Value\":\"\"},{\"Name\":\"CustomerArea\",\"$type\":\"Text\",\"Value\":\"\"},{\"Name\":\"CustomerAddress\",\"$type\":\"Text\",\"SuspiciousSymbols\":\"11000000\",\"RecognizedValue\":\"\",\"Value\":\"\"},{\"Name\":\"DocumentGUID\",\"$type\":\"Text\",\"Value\":\"\"},{\"Name\":\"DocumentProposalID\",\"$type\":\"Text\",\"Value\":\"\"},{\"Name\":\"DocumentCountry\",\"$type\":\"Text\",\"SuspiciousSymbols\":\"000\",\"RecognizedValue\":\"FRA\",\"Value\":\"FRA\"},{\"Name\":\"DocumentCurrency\",\"$type\":\"Text\",\"SuspiciousSymbols\":\"000\",\"RecognizedValue\":\"EUR\",\"Value\":\"EUR\"},{\"Name\":\"DocumentTo\",\"$type\":\"Text\",\"Value\":\"\"},{\"Name\":\"DocumentFrom\",\"$type\":\"Text\",\"Value\":\"\"},{\"Name\":\"DocumentTotalNumberOfPages\",\"$type\":\"Text\",\"SuspiciousSymbols\":\"0\",\"RecognizedValue\":\"1\",\"Value\":\"1\"}]}}]}";
Console.WriteLine(jsonText);
var documentResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DocumentDTO>(jsonText);
```

and my class objects are below

```
 public class DocumentDTO
     {
        public string Version { get; set; }
        public List<DocumentInfo> Documents { get; set; }

     }
    public class DocumentInfo
    {
        public string DocumentState { get; set; }
        public DocumentData DocumentData { get; set; }
        public string DocumentAsBase64 { get; set; }
    }
    public class DocumentData
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [JsonPropertyName("$type")]
        public string type { get; set; }
        public List<DocumentField> Fields { get; set; }
    }
    public class DocumentField
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [JsonPropertyName("$type")]
        public string type { get; set; }
        public string SuspiciousSymbols { get; set; }
        public string RecognizedValue { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }
```

but it is not working not converting `$type` to `type`. How can I solve this problem ?

Thanks in advance
Kind Regards

Comment: FYI - `$type` is usually a hint to Json.Net telling it what type the current structure should be deserialised to. However, it normally includes the full namespace.

Comment: The `JsonPropertyNameAttribute` is from System.Text.Json whereas Json.Net uses `JsonPropertyAttribute`. Have you tried using `[JsonProperty("$type")]` instead?

Answer (score 1):

That's because you're using `JsonConvert` from `Newtonsoft.Json` library and are marking property with `JsonPropertyName` attribute from `System.Text.Json.Serialization`. The two just don't play well together. Try replacing your `JsonPropertyName` with `JsonProperty` attribute from `Newtonsoft.Json` and it should work.

```
public class DocumentData
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("$type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public List<DocumentField> Fields { get; set; }
}

public class DocumentField
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("$type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string SuspiciousSymbols { get; set; }
    public string RecognizedValue { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```